# Join two collecions which is diffrent database in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to join the following two collecions.
But, these collecions are different databases.

```
> use test
> db.payment_history.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbbaf12f5908ec24b3a9"), "user_id" : 1233, "cash_id" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbbcf12f5908ec24b3aa"), "user_id" : 1233, "cash_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bba5f12f5908ec24b3a5"), "user_id" : 1234, "cash_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbaaf12f5908ec24b3a6"), "user_id" : 1235, "cash_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbaff12f5908ec24b3a7"), "user_id" : 1235, "cash_id" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbb5f12f5908ec24b3a8"), "user_id" : 1236, "cash_id" : 3 }
> use test_mst
> db.mst_cash.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbebf12f5908ec24b3ab"), "cash_id" : 1, "num" : 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbf1f12f5908ec24b3ac"), "cash_id" : 2, "num" : 200 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbf8f12f5908ec24b3ad"), "cash_id" : 3, "num" : 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbfff12f5908ec24b3ae"), "cash_id" : 4, "num" : 1000 }
```

I want to output of joined like the following.
(relation key is cash_id)

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbbaf12f5908ec24b3a9"), "user_id" : 1233, "cash_id" : 3, "num": 500 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbbcf12f5908ec24b3aa"), "user_id" : 1233, "cash_id" : 1, "num": 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bba5f12f5908ec24b3a5"), "user_id" : 1234, "cash_id" : 1, "num": 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbaaf12f5908ec24b3a6"), "user_id" : 1235, "cash_id" : 1, "num": 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbaff12f5908ec24b3a7"), "user_id" : 1235, "cash_id" : 1, "num": 100 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbb5f12f5908ec24b3a8"), "user_id" : 1236, "cash_id" : 3, "num": 500 }
```

I try to write javascript like the following.

```
> var map_1 = function(){ emit(this._id, {user_id: this.user_id, cash_id: this.cash_id}) };

> var map_2 = function(){ emit(this.cash_id, {num: this.num}) };

> var r = function(key, values){
    var result = {"cash_id": 0};
    values.forEach(function(v){
        result.cash_id = v.cash_id;
    });

    return result;
  };

> var r2 = function(key, values){
      var result = {"num": 0};
      values.forEach(function(v){
          result.num = v.num;
       });

      return result;
  };

> db.payment_history.mapReduce(map_1, r, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}});
> db.getSiblingDB('test_mst').mst_cash.mapReduce(map_2, r2, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}});
```

But, joined collecion isn't merged result of mst_cash data.
I make sure that 'db.getSiblingDB('test_mst').mst_cash.mapReduce(map_2, r2, {out: {reduce: 'joined'}});' create joined collecion in test_mst database.
I want to merge mst_cash data to joined collecion in test database.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first - mongo does not offer operations on different databases.

To ***join*** collections, they have to be is same database, then we can utilize aggregation framework like snippet below:

```
var lookUp = {
    $lookup : {
        from : "mst_cash",
        localField : "cash_id",
        foreignField : "cash_id",
        as : "operations"
    }
}

var unwind = {
    $unwind : "$operations"
}

var project = {
    $project : {
        _id : 1,
        "user_id" : 1,
        "cash_id" : 1,
        "num" : "$operations.num"
    }
}



db.payment_history.aggregate([lookUp, unwind, project])
```

And result of that query is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5752bbbaf12f5908ec24b3a9"),
    "user_id" : 1233.0,
    "cash_id" : 3.0,
    "num" : 500.0
}
```

Comment: I do understand.
Thank you for your answer